# Retag [splash] questions with the [splash-screen] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

When asking a (very) recent question, I noticed that [splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash) and [splash-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash-screen) exist, but mean exactly the same thing:

[image: Tag definitions]

Surely the [splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash) tag could easily be confused with another software development-related thing, like an SDK.

I'm requesting that the [splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash) be merged into the (far more popular) [splash-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash-screen), since it makes far more sense and it eases confusion.

Comment: Agreed: the [tag:splash] tag wiki practically points you to [tag:splash-screen].

Comment: Are both tags are actually useful?

Comment: @Braiam They both mean the same thing, and the [tag:splash-screen] has almost ten times the amount of questions [tag:splash] does.

Answer (score 7):

Going to answer this to try to gain some attention / traction, as I just submitted [the same (duplicate) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286216/merge-splash-into-splash-screen?noredirect=1).

I agree, [splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash) should be merged into [splash-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splash-screen). It's more descriptive and has far more questions.